# jquery: removing everything after an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html code like this:

```
<li>
<a href=''>Example</a>&nbsp;<a href='' class='sub'>Edit</a>&nbsp;<a href='' class='sub'>Delete</a>
</li>
```

and I want to remove everything after the first `</a>`, including the spaces. What is the most elegant and simple way to do this?
I have achieved my purpose with the following jquery:

```
$('li').children(".sub").remove();    
$('li').html($('li').html().replace(/&nbsp;/g,''));
```

but the second line looks too much like a hack. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
$('li').html($('li a:first-child'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this instead:

```
$('li a:first-child').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().html(this);
});​
```

This would clean out the parent including event handlers on those elements then put the first `<a>` back.  It would also maintain any event handlers on the anchor you're keeping, [you can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Vp47G/1/).  Passing a DOM element to [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is [a shortcut](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L261) for [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) and [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), just making it a bit more terse.

Comment: Thanks for the link to jsfiddle, looks like a very useful site!

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
$('li').html($('li').find("a:first").html())
```

EDIT 1: The above code is wrong. Try the following:

```
$('li').find("a:first").appendTo($('li').html(""));
```

Thanks Nick.

Comment: This would append the HTML *inside* the anchor, not keeping the anchor :)

Comment: Are you sure? I've tested it and it works... $('li').find("a:first").html() gets the html of the anchor. The answer should be the code that gives <li><a..>Example</a></li>.

Comment: Yup, try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Vp47G/2/ notice "Example" is no longer a link :)

Comment: Thanks, you're right... I put it in one line again :). But this time it works.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to perhaps wrap the Edit/Delete links you're wanting to remove inside of a div (or other element of your choice) and then remove it all at once. You're almost there with the first line of code.

Instead of putting a class='sub' on each anchor, you could instead do something like:

```
<li>
<a href=''>Example</a><div class='sub'>&nbsp;<a href=''>Edit</a>&nbsp;<a href=''>Delete</a></div>
</li>
```

And then you'd have:

```
$('li').children(".sub").remove();
```

Just as you currently do, and it should remove the div, with the spaces.

Comment: That's a good suggestion and I may end up having to do it like that but for now I'd prefer to use as little extra html, as possible. With Mic's suggestion, I can even get rid of the ".sub" class.